# ASP.net MVC How to change the Textbox Class upon validation failure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, textbox, highlight

I notice in the default MVC template project that the Account registration fields are highlighted via a class change.

I can't seem to get the same behaviour out of my own code (in the same project - same CSS etc)

What might be stopping this from occurring?

**Update**

I believe this relates to [one of my other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633365/asp-net-mvc-rc2-validationmessage-and-checkbox-conflict/633400#633400) 
Because I was having trouble with NullReferenceExceptions I have changed the Html.ValidationMessage fields to have different names than the target fields.

So really, I need to resolve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633365/asp-net-mvc-rc2-validationmessage-and-checkbox-conflict/633400#633400) question

Comment: Right, I think your other question is really the issue at hand. Once you solve the other issue, this one will go away.